# Question regarding the new custom chapter rules

Tags: warhammer-40k

So recently this year, games workshop has added the addition of custom chapters to Warhammer, and while building my army I realised that I was going with a space wolves kind of army. However while painting and lore building I was making the chapter a salamanders successor.

So what I was gonna ask is, how do custom chapter rules work regarding chapter specific units, could I say that they're a successor chapter to the salamanders and use some data sheets specific to the space wolves like thunderwolf cavalry and fenrisian wolves, while abandoning salamander specific data sheets.

Do I have to use salamander units specifically now that I've made them salamanders in paint scheme and lore.

Or can custom chapters just flat out not use chapter specific units. (I don't know too much on the custom chapter rules so I apologize if I'm being dumb)

Answer (score 3):

You have three options for a battle-forged army.

Firstly, you can have a Space Wolves successor chapter that is painted green and fiery. You can take datasheets that have the `SPACE WOLVES` keyword (such as thunderwolf cavalry and fenrisian wolves), and pick two successor chapter tactics (or Inheritors of the Primarch for Hunters Unleashed). You could use Space Wolves stratagems, your Warlord could take a Space Wolves warlord trait, and/or take Relics of the Fang. Your "super doctrine" would be Savage Fury.

Secondly, you can have a Salamanders successor. You can't take thunderwolf cavalry and fenrisian wolves, but you can take a pair of successor chapter tactics (or Forged in Battle). Then you can use Salamanders stratagems, warlord trait and relics. Your "super doctrine" would be Promethean Cult.

Thirdly, you take the `SPACE WOLVES` (successor) units that you want in one detachment, and `SALAMANDERS` (successor) units in another detachment. Each detachment gets it's own chapter tactic. You don't get either Savage Fury nor Promethean Cult, as those require your whole army be `SPACE WOLVES` or `SALAMANDERS` respectively.